# Find $\mathscr{Z}$ transform of $\begin{cases}(\frac{1}{2})^{-n}&\text{if $n$ is a multiple of 3},\\1&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, z-transform

1. Find $\mathscr{Z}$ transform of the following discrete signal: $$x[n]=\begin{cases}\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-n}&\text{if $n$ is a multiple of 3},\\1&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
2. Find radius and graph radius of convergence of the $\mathscr{Z}$ transform of the previous signal.

---

I know that $$\mathscr{Z}(x[n])=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x[n]z^{-n}.$$ and $$x[n]=\begin{cases}\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-n}&n=3k,\\1&n\neq3k.\end{cases}$$ However, the "$1$" is bothering me.

If I had this signal: $$y[n]=\begin{cases}\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-n}&n=3k,\\\color{red}0&n\neq3k.\end{cases}$$ then, as $\{y[n]\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\{1,0,0,2^3,0,0,2^6,0,0,2^9,\ldots\}$ we can say: $$\mathscr{Z}(y[n])=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y[3n]z^{-3n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-3n}z^{-3n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{8}{z^3}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{1-\frac{8}{z^3}}=\boxed{\frac{z^3}{z^3-8}},$$ and $|z|<2$.

---

But here we have $\{x[n]\}_{n\in\Bbb N}=\{1,1,1,2^3,1,1,2^6,1,1,2^9,\ldots\}$ and I do not know how to interpret the $1$'s. Maybe the transform is $\fbox{$(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x[3n]z^{-3n})+1=z^3/(z^3+8)+1$}$?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You can write the $\mathscr{Z}$-transform of $x[n]$ as $$ \mathscr{Z}(x[n]) = \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} x[3n] z^{-3n} + \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} x[3n + 1] z^{-(3n+1)} + \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} x[3n+2] z^{-(3n+2)}$$

You can deal with the first part as you have done for $y[n]$ and the second and the third part are simply the $\mathscr{Z}$-transform of the constant sequence $u[n] = 1 \ \forall \ n$ evaluated at $z^3$ and offset by $z^{-1}$ and $z^{-2}$ respectively. Just evaluate them all and add them up. I believe the final answer should be $\displaystyle \mathscr{Z}(x[n]) = \frac{z^3}{z^3 - 8} + \frac{z^2 + z}{z^3 - 1}$ and the region of convergence would be $|z| > 2$. Note that you have flipped the sign in the region of convergence in the question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the second summand I get: $$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} x[3n + 1] z^{-(3n+1)}=\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac12\right)^{-(3n+1)} z^{-(3n+1)}=\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac z2\right)^{-(3n+1)}=\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \left(\frac z2\right)^{-3n} \left(\frac z2\right)^{-1}=\frac2z\frac{1}{1-\frac{8}{z^3}}=\frac2z\frac{z^3}{z^3-8}=\frac{2z^2}{z^3-8}.$$ Similarly, $$\sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} x[3n + 2] z^{-(3n+2)}=\frac{4}{z^2}\frac{z^3}{z^3-8}=\frac{4z}{z^3-8},$$ and $$\frac{2z^2}{z^3-8}+\frac{4z}{z^3-8}=\frac{2z^2+4z}{z^3-8}\neq\frac{z^2+z}{z^3-1}.$$ Am I wrong?

Comment: $x[3n + 1] = 1$ is a constant sequence. And so is $x[3n+2]$. You have also taken them to be $2^{-(3n+1)}$ and $2^{-(3n+2)}$ respectively and hence the discrepancy.